# Javascript on HTML opened with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a little html page that includes this Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#select1").change(function() {
                    var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                    $("#select2 option").removeAttr("disabled").removeAttr("selected");
                    $("#select2 option").each(function() {
                        if($(this).val() != selectedVal && $(this).val() != -1)
                            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled").removeAttr("selected"); 
                    });
                });
            });
     </script>
```

This HTML page is generated by python with the code:

```
f = open.('template.html', 'r')
 template = f.read()
 print template
```

If i have the script on the HTML python wont work and say me that i have a syntax error in the HTML, but if i delete the script, python open the HTML (without the JS function).
Why python don't recognize the JS? I need help! How can i implement my script?

Comment: Firstly, that's invalid Python code. Also, how are you parsing/generating the code? What you've shown doesn't appear to do too much with it.

Comment: That is only a little part of my code! This is how i open the html. That is the error: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: '\n\t\t\t $("#select1")' 
      args = ('\n\t\t\t $("#select1")',) 
      message = '\n\t\t\t $("#select1")'

Comment: Without the script all works fine, but i need to implement that because i lost an important function of my page!